# NextJS Can you call a fetch in a utility class?

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, next.js

I'm running into errors when I try to call an api endpoint such as the one below in a utility file. What I mean is I have a file which is not a page but only stores API calls.

```
export const getProducts = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/products`);
  const products = await resp.json();
  return products;
}
```

Is this not allowed? Whenever I try it in production it's giving me a 504 time out, whereas if I put this method directly inside the page file and call it, it's fine. On localhost either way works.. Can someone clear this up for me?

**Example:
---- Option 1 ----**

Everything in React component (works)

```
export const getProducts = async () => {
  const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/products`);
  const products = await resp.json();
  setProducts(products);
}

// Works
useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
}, []);
```

**----- Option 2 (does not work in production(!)) -----**

Utility.js

```
export const getProducts = async (setProducts) => {
  const resp = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/products`);
  const products = await resp.json();
  setProducts(products);
}
```

React component

```
// Does not work
useEffect(() => {
    getProducts(setProducts);
}, []);
```

Comment: how did you pass context to getProducts? and where did you use this function?

Comment: And where are you calling `getProducts`? Please make it a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @AliSattarzadeh I've added my exact code to my post, context was a mistake, it's not used

Comment: @yousoumar I've added my exact code to my post, could you please check if it looks good?

Comment: Could you try adding an await in front of your getProducts call to make it execute on the same thread?